# Рефлексия структур C++

Tags: c++, struct, рефлексия

Есть ли в стандартном C++17 рефлексия связанная со структурами? 
Интересуют следующие возможности:

```
numfields - количество полей структуры
name - имя поля структуры
```

Если есть, то как их более-менее гуманно реализовать эту рефлексию чтоб не писать сотни строк кода?

Нужно работать со структурами, где заранее не знаешь сколько полей у структуры и какие поля у структуры, передаешь шаблон `T` в качестве аргумента функции, далее взаимодействуешь с полями структуры. Вот образный пример:

```
template <typename T>
void Get(T *prop)
{

    // Образно: v - поле структуры
    // typeid(v) - получить тип поля структуры
    // typeid(v).name() - получить имя поля структуры
    for (auto const & v : prop)
    {
        // index 0 - v.Name, index 1 - v.Count ...
        // or index 0 - v.Name, index 1 - v.Model ...
        std::wcout << "Field name: " << typeid(v).name() << std::endl;
        std::wcout << "Field value: " << v << std::endl;
    }
}

struct User
{
    wchar_t *Name;
    size_t Count;
};

struct Car
{
    wchar_t *Name;
    wchar_t *Model;
};

int main(void)
{
    User* u = new User;
    u->Name = L"Simple anandnsand";
    u->Count = 123;
    Get(u);
    delete u;

    Car* c = new Car;
    c->Name = L"Ford";
    c->Model = L"Corsair";
    Get(c);
    delete c;
}
```

Можно передавать как явную структуру и работать с явными полями, но таких структур может быть более 600 и писать реализацию под каждую структуру будет очень муторно и глупо.

Comment: Нет, никакой готовой рефлексии в С++ нет. Если вам нужна такая рефлексия, вам придется теми или иными способами более или менее явно сохранять необходимую для рефлексии информацию. Именно так работают любые библиотеки эмуляции "рефлексии" для С++. То есть для ваших типов `User` и `Car`, при именно таких "традиционных" их объявлениях, никакой рефлексии быть не может.

Comment: @AnT эх... понятно(

Comment: В фреймворке Qt рефлексия весьма развита. Вас интересуют метод `qRegisterMetaType`, класс `QMetaMethod`, `QMetaObject`.